# pysimplegui popup button_justification problem

Tags: python, button, popup, pysimplegui

According to the [documentation](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/) of PySimpleGUI, the popup element should have an argument called `button_justification`, which position the button in `'right'` or `'left'`, or `'center'` within the popup window.

When i added `button_justification='center'` to the popup element in my project it raised the error: `popup() got an unexpected keyword argument 'button_justification'`. What's the problem?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niU2w.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all enhancements added into the PyPI version.
[Download from GitHub](https://www.pysimplegui.org/en/latest/#upgrading-from-github-using-pysimplegui)

> There is code in the PySimpleGUI package that upgrades your previously pip installed package to the latest version checked into GitHub.
> You can use the commands `psgmain` to run the test harness or `psgupgrade` to invoke the GitHub upgrade code.

or, you can call `sg.main()`, like

```py
d:\>python
Python 3.10.2 (tags/v3.10.2:a58ebcc, Jan 17 2022, 14:12:15) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PySimpleGUI as sg
>>> sg.main()
```

[image]